# excel vba: function return value strange

Tags: excel, function, vba

I have an EXCEL VBA function which should return the address of the first cell where the cell value is greater zero but it is not working. Does anyone has an idea why?

Code:

```
Function FindNextFilledCell(RowArray() As Integer, ColArray() As Integer)

For i = UBound(ColArray) To 0
    For j = UBound(RowArray) To 0
        CellValue = cells(RowArray(j), ColArray(i)).Value
        If CellValue > 0 Then
            FindNextFilledCell = cells(RowArray(j), ColArray(i)).Address(False, False)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: To start with a backwards `For` loop needs a `Step -1` to descend by 1, `For i = UBound(ColArray) To 0 Step -1`. How are you calling this function?

Comment: @brettdj: I have never seen so far a negative UBound... I would say you should post this as an answer :)

Comment: @Jmax Perhaps I should have :). But I didn't as I think the function should be reworked once we understand what it is doing - I doubt the loop is neccesary

Comment: @brettdj.  Sorry your comment was before my first answer.  You get warned if some one has posted an answer while you were typing but not if they post an answer.

Comment: @TonyDallimore You have nothing to apologise for, it was a lineball call for me to post this as an answer or comment.

Comment: How are you calling and using this function? There is scope for improvement

Comment: I use it in another for loop which iterates over a matrix and checks for negative values. If a negative value is found the aforementioned function is called (I don't know how to make it faster) to find the next cell which has a positive value. I have to get rid of all negative values in the matrix but the overall sum of entries must remain the same. So for example negative value is -78 and next positive is 20 than next positive is set to 0 and -78 to -58 and so on until there are no negative entries any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still trying to understand what you are trying to do but I suggest the first error is:

```
For i = UBound(ColArray) To 0
```

instead of

```
For i = UBound(ColArray) To 0 step -1
```

This assumes you meant to search the cells in reverse order.  If you did not

```
For i = 0 to UBound(ColArray)
```

might be better.

The next error I have spotted is that you have not defined the type of the value returned by the function. Try:

```
FindNextFilledCell(RowArray() As Integer, ColArray() As Integer) As String
```